# How to escape %> in asp .net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following code in my view

```
<%: "bla bla %>" %>
```

The problem is, the "%>" inside the string is being recognized as the closing tag. How to make it being treated as normal string instead of a closing tag?

RWendi

Comment: In Razor, we skip `@` with another `@` : my@@email.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a quick fix as follows:

```
<%= Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("bla bla &#37;&#62;")) %>
```

Would be great if there's a built in way of solving this.

Comment: &#62; can be simplified to &gt;

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can split the C# string: `<%: "bla bla %" + ">" %>`.

Or you can use the C# escape syntax: `<%: "bla bla \u0025>" %>`.